# Agda input method, Σ ⇛ ⇒, and Latex export

Tags: emacs, unicode, latex

I can use [agda input method](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Docs.UnicodeInput) in emacs to type effortlessly a gazillion unicode character in my nice beamer presentation.

Now I want to process it with latex and I apparently have to map each missing unicode from utf8 package by hand

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

% missing Welsh coverage
\newunicodechar{Ŵ}{\^W}
\newunicodechar{ŵ}{\^w}
\newunicodechar{Ŷ}{\^Y}
\newunicodechar{ŷ}{\^y}
....
```

What is the way to avoid to do this by hand ?

How is it possible that every browser or editor out there support natively things like Σ ⇛ ⇒ and Latex, the **ONE system** to type mathematics does not natively ? Did I miss something ??